# Trying to write a regular expression to remove all text after date in any given string

Tags: r

Need to remove all the text from any given string after the date part, which is mentioned as duration with a hyphen in between

For e.g.,
x = "AB - CEPC - Telephone_BAU_CPM_Link - 20Jan22 - 30Jan22 - Video Package - XXXX - Optimize"

Expression I'm currently using:
gsub("[0-9 A-Z a-z]*[22] \- [0-9 A-Z a-z]*[22].*", "\1", x)

Output: AB - CEPC - Telephone_BAU_CPM_Link - 20Jan22 - 30Jan22

However, the space before & after the hyphen might not be present always, for e.g.,

x = "AB - CEPC - Telephone_BAU_CPM_Link - 20Jan22-30Jan22 - Video Package - XXXX - Optimize"

The above mentioned regex isn't working in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `sub()` here with a capture group:

```
x <- "AB - CEPC - Telephone_BAU_CPM_Link - 2Jan22-30Jan22 - Video Package - XXXX - Optimize"
output <- sub("(.*\\b\\d{1,2}[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\d{2}\\s*-\\s*\\d{1,2}[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\d{2})\\b.*", "\\1", x)
output

[1] "AB - CEPC - Telephone_BAU_CPM_Link - 2Jan22-30Jan22"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working. However, its giving incorrect output in case of single digit dates. For e.g., x = "AB - CEPC - Telephone_BAU_CPM_Link - 2Jan22-30Jan22 - Video Package - XXXX - Optimize"

Comment: Also, can I check for multiple years? x = "AB - CEPC - Telephone_BAU_CPM_Link - 2Dec21-30Jan22 - Video Package - XXXX - Optimize"

Comment: I have updated my answer.  BTW...grammar check, `e.g.` already means "for example", so using "for e.g." makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea. Very similar to the other, but I modified a little bit just in case the date is not always 2 num, 3 letter, 2 num. Maybe you might have "5Jan22-10Jan22". Maybe it would always read "05Jan22-10Jan22" and this wouldn't be an issue.

```r
x = "AB - CEPC - Telephone_BAU_CPM_Link - 20Jan22-30Jan22 - Video Package - XXXX - Optimize"

sub("(^.*\\d{1,2}[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\d{2}.*\\d{1,2}[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\d{2}).*$", "\\1", x)
#> [1] "AB - CEPC - Telephone_BAU_CPM_Link - 20Jan22-30Jan22"
```